# High-probability tail bounds for a quantitative supermartingale inequality.

Tags: stochastic-processes, dynamical-systems, conditional-probability, martingales

Let $(Y_t)_{t \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a **non-negative** stochastic process and $c \in (0,1)$.

Suppose that $Y_1 = 1$ and that for all $t \in \mathbb{N}$ it holds that
$$\mathbb{E}[Y_{t+1} \mid Y_1,\dots, Y_t] \le Y_t-cY_t^2.$$
Notice that this last inequality tells us that the process $(Y_t)_{t \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a (non-negative) supermartingale with the expected decreasing being at least $-c Y_t^2$.

> Is it true that there exists $a,b>0$ and $T_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $t \ge T_0$ it holds that $\mathbb{P}[Y_t > \frac{a}{t}] \le \frac{b}{\sqrt{t}}$?
> If it is false, what if we add the further assumptions that the process is decreasing (i.e., $Y_{t+1}\le Y_t$ for all $t \in \mathbb{N}$) and/or that $(Y_t)_{t \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a Markov chain and/or we content ourselves with the same type of bound up to polylogarithmic terms (both in the rate of shrinking and in the probability shrinking)?

What I did so far.

I realized that getting the expectation on the last inequality and using the fact that $\mathbb{E}[Y_t^2] - (\mathbb{E}[Y_t])^2 = \mathrm{Var}[Y_t] \ge 0$ we can get $\mathbb{E}[Y_{t+1}] \le \mathbb{E}[Y_{t}]-c(\mathbb{E}[Y_{t}])^2$. Defining $x_t := \mathbb{E}[Y_t]$ we get that $(x_t)_{t \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a non-negative sequence, and the recursion $x_{t+1} \le x_{t}-cx_t^2$. By induction, we can prove that $x_t \le \frac{1}{1+c(t-1)}$. In fact, this is trivial for $t=1$ since $x_1 = \mathbb{E}[Y_1] = 1$, and assuming the hypothesis holds for $t$, we have that
\begin{align*}
   x_{t+1}
&\le
   x_{t}-cx_t^2
=
   x_{t}(1-cx_t)
=
   \frac{x_{t}(1-cx_t)(1+cx_t)}{1+cx_t}
\\
&=
   \frac{x_{t}(1-c^2x_t^2)}{1+cx_t}
\le
   \frac{x_{t}}{1+cx_t}
\le
   \frac{\frac{1}{1+c(t-1)}}{1+c \frac{1}{1+c(t-1)}}
\\
&=
   \frac{1}{1+ct}
=
   \frac{1}{1+c\big((t+1)-1\big)}
\end{align*}
proving the claim by induction (we have used the fact that the function $x \mapsto \frac{x}{1+cx}$ is monotone increasing for $x \in [0,1]$).

Then, we have obtained that $\mathbb{E}[Y_t] \le \frac{1}{1+c(t-1)}$, which means that, at least in expectation, the process is going down as fast as we want.

Now, using Markov inequality we trivially get, for $\gamma > 0$
$$
   \mathbb{P}\bigg[Y_t \ge \frac{1}{(1+c(t-1))^\gamma}\bigg]\le \frac{1}{(1+c(t-1))^{1-\gamma}}
$$
which, for $\gamma = 1/2$, gives us a much weaker result than I hoped for in terms of the rate at which $Y_t$ shrinks to $0$ with a probability of at least $1-\frac{b}{\sqrt{t}}$.

Does anyone have any idea on how to get the improved result or maybe see a counterexample proving that the desired result is too good to be achieved?